# PHP Xpath to remove <br />?

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I am using xpath to remove `<br />` from nodes with this code below,

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//p[node()[1][self::br]]/br[1] | //p[node()[last()][self::br]]/br[last()] | //*[node()[last()][self::br]]/br[last()]");
foreach($nodeList as $node) 
{
   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

So it removes `<p>Text<strong><br /></strong></p>` to `<p>Text</p>` which is perfect.

But I don't want it to remove `<br />` from `<p>Text<strong>Bold<br /></strong>Break</p>` because the are text after `<br />`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean `<br />` everywhere that you say `</br>`?

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake. Amended that...

Comment: thanks hakre. how can I determine a parent node is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the node value of the `<br>`'s parent element node is an empty string, you want to remove it. That probably matches your needs better:

```
//br[string(..) = '']
```

A code example that shows which one is matching those (adds a *remove* attribute):

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string('
<root>
   <p>Text<strong><br /></strong></p>
   <p>Text<strong>Bold<br /></strong></p>
</root>
');

foreach($xml->xpath('//br[string(..) = ""]') as $br) {
    $br['remove'] = 'remove';
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output ([Demo](http://codepad.org/3yNIGGVS)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
   <p>Text<strong><br remove="remove"/></strong></p>
   <p>Text<strong>Bold<br/></strong></p>
</root>
```